# Carrierwave check if remote file exists via fog

Tags: ruby-on-rails, carrierwave, fog

I know I'm missing something really easy here...

`CarrierWave::Storage::Fog::File` has a method [exists](https://github.com/jnicklas/carrierwave/blob/master/lib/carrierwave/storage/fog.rb)?

How do I use it?   I'm just trying to check whether a previously uploaded file exists on the remote storage.

Neither my image object, nor my uploader object have access to this method.  Surely I don't have to create a new `CarrierWave::Storage::Fog::File` object to test if the file exists?

If so, what parameters should I put in?   It takes the following: uploader, base, path
(I used the uploader, store directory and image url, but that didn't work)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Suppose you have model User with a field image that you use Carrierwave on. 
You could now write:

```
user = User.first
user.image.file.exists?
```

This would execute a remote check that returns true or false

Comment: Although this works, it is slow to execute since it is doing a remote check, especially if you are doing it on multiple images on a page.

Comment: How can i check file exists or is uploaded before saving it to database?(Using S3 for Storage, CarrierWave & Dropzone.js for Uploading)